# Call method when condition is true for certain length of time

Tags: java, android, timer, android-handler

I want to create a method whereby if `state_i = 1` for `time` seconds, call method `alert_box()` , where time is a previously user selected value in seconds.

I'm unsure if I should use a `handler.postDelayed` or a timer or a while loop to implement this or possibly another method?

The purpose is to show an alert box once a user has their eyes closed for a certain amount of time.

Thank you

**eye_tracking method**

```
      private void eye_tracking(Face face) {
            float l = face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability();
            float r = face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability();

            if (l > THRESHOLD || r > THRESHOLD) {
                state_i = 0;
                Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Open Eyes Detected");
            } else {
                state_i = 1;
                Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Closed Eyes Detected");
             
              //If state_i = 1 for *time* seconds, call method alert_box();

            }
```

Comment: How frequent is eye_tracking() called?

Comment: It is running all the time that my activity is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `eye_tracking()` is being called continuously, we can use this to our advantage. We will store the time that the last time the eyes switched state (i.e. was open and now closed). Then in `eye_tracking()` we will check every time we see a closed eye if the time was elapsed 1000ms in this case, then we can call our function. Whenever the eyes open we will start the cycle again once they are closed.

### Sample Code:

```
boolean firstTime = true;
long lastLowToHighState = 0;
private void eye_tracking(Face face) {
    float l = face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability();
    float r = face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability();

    if (l > THRESHOLD || r > THRESHOLD) {
        state_i = 0;
        firstTime = true;
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Open Eyes Detected");
    } else {
        if (state_i == 0) {
            lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        } else if (firstTime && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLowToHighState > 1000) {
            // Used to prevent the function from continously firing
            lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            firstTime = false;
            
            // Call Your Method Here
        }
        state_i = 1;
        Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Closed Eyes Detected");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will check this and report back.

Comment: Most Welcome, I am glad I was able to help you

Comment: My function is getting called every time the user's eyes are closed for 1000ms consecutively, i.e if the eyes are closed for 5 seconds, my function will be called 5 times. This is undesirable as a dialog box appears, which means 5 dialogs are shown. Is there a way to make my function run until the eyes are reopened, without calling the function every 1000ms? Thank you

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I thought that was the desirable behavior. In order to prevent this, you will need to add a boolean to check whether the pop-up appeared or not. Based on that you will decide whether to show the pop-up or not. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that works as desired now. You have been very helpful!

Comment: Most welcome, glad I was able to help you :-)